# Sample size (sampsize) argument in cforest()?

Tags: r, tree, random-forest

I've been working with the RandomForest package in R, which is great for classification yet weak when it comes to calculating variable importance for datasets with  highly correlated predictors (like mine) 
I want to switch over to the party package (to use cforest) but I can't find the equivalent of the sampsize argument when using cforest(), this argument is particularly important for me because I have a highly imbalanced dataset and have to use sampling methods to cope with that problem.

Alternatively, is there a way to pass a randomForest forest to cforest (Can s3 objects be transformed into s4 objects?!) I can train the classifier in randomForest and use the party package to get the variable importance....

Many thanks...